# How to retrieve OID value using Net SNMP in C?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I am new to this. I am trying to use Net-SNMP's snmpget file to retrieve an OID and store it in a variable. Where can I specify the IP address of the device I am querying? Where can I specify what OID I am looking for? And how can I store the value of the OID?

I already know the IP address of my device and the OID I am looking for.

Here is the code Net-SNMP provides for snmpget:

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>

#if HAVE_STDLIB_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#if HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#if HAVE_STRING_H
#include <string.h>
#else
#include <strings.h>
#endif
#include <sys/types.h>
#if HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#if TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <time.h>
#else
# if HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
#  include <sys/time.h>
# else
#  include <time.h>
# endif
#endif
#if HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif
#if HAVE_NETDB_H
#include <netdb.h>
#endif
#if HAVE_ARPA_INET_H
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <net-snmp/utilities.h>

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

#define NETSNMP_DS_APP_DONT_FIX_PDUS 0

static void
optProc(int argc, char *const *argv, int opt)
{
    switch (opt) {
    case 'C':
        while (*optarg) {
            switch (*optarg++) {
            case 'f':
                netsnmp_ds_toggle_boolean(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, 
                      NETSNMP_DS_APP_DONT_FIX_PDUS);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown flag passed to -C: %c\n",
                        optarg[-1]);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

void
usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: snmpget ");
    snmp_parse_args_usage(stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, " OID [OID]...\n\n");
    snmp_parse_args_descriptions(stderr);
    fprintf(stderr,
            "  -C APPOPTS\t\tSet various application specific     behaviours:\n");
    fprintf(stderr,
            "\t\t\t  f:  do not fix errors and retry the request\n");
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    netsnmp_session session, *ss;
    netsnmp_pdu    *pdu;
    netsnmp_pdu    *response;
    netsnmp_variable_list *vars;
    int             arg;
    int             count;
    int             current_name = 0;
    char           *names[SNMP_MAX_CMDLINE_OIDS];
    oid             name[MAX_OID_LEN];
    size_t          name_length;
    int             status;
    int             failures = 0;
    int             exitval = 0;


    /*
     * get the common command line arguments 
     */
    switch (arg = snmp_parse_args(argc, argv, &session, "C:", optProc)) {
    case NETSNMP_PARSE_ARGS_ERROR:
        exit(1);
    case NETSNMP_PARSE_ARGS_SUCCESS_EXIT:
        exit(0);
    case NETSNMP_PARSE_ARGS_ERROR_USAGE:
        usage();
        exit(1);
    default:
    break;
    }

    if (arg >= argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing object name\n");
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((argc - arg) > SNMP_MAX_CMDLINE_OIDS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many object identifiers specified. ");
        fprintf(stderr, "Only %d allowed in one request.\n",         SNMP_MAX_CMDLINE_OIDS);
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * get the object names 
     */
    for (; arg < argc; arg++)
        names[current_name++] = argv[arg];

    SOCK_STARTUP;


    /*
     * Open an SNMP session.
     */
    ss = snmp_open(&session);
    if (ss == NULL) {
        /*
         * diagnose snmp_open errors with the input netsnmp_session pointer 
         */
        snmp_sess_perror("snmpget", &session);
        SOCK_CLEANUP;
        exit(1);
    }


    /*
     * Create PDU for GET request and add object names to request.
     */
    pdu = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_GET);
    for (count = 0; count < current_name; count++) {
        name_length = MAX_OID_LEN;
        if (!snmp_parse_oid(names[count], name, &name_length)) {
            snmp_perror(names[count]);
            failures++;
        } else
            snmp_add_null_var(pdu, name, name_length);
    }
    if (failures) {
        snmp_close(ss);
        SOCK_CLEANUP;
        exit(1);
    }


    /*
     * Perform the request.
     *
     * If the Get Request fails, note the OID that caused the error,
     * "fix" the PDU (removing the error-prone OID) and retry.
     */
  retry:
    status = snmp_synch_response(ss, pdu, &response);
    if (status == STAT_SUCCESS) {
        if (response->errstat == SNMP_ERR_NOERROR) {
            for (vars = response->variables; vars;
                 vars = vars->next_variable)
                print_variable(vars->name, vars->name_length, vars);

        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in packet\nReason: %s\n",
                    snmp_errstring(response->errstat));

            if (response->errindex != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed object: ");
                for (count = 1, vars = response->variables;
                     vars && count != response->errindex;
                     vars = vars->next_variable, count++)
                /*EMPTY*/;
                if (vars) {
                    fprint_objid(stderr, vars->name, vars->name_length);
        }
                fprintf(stderr, "\n");
            }
            exitval = 2;

            /*
             * retry if the errored variable was successfully removed 
             */
            if (!netsnmp_ds_get_boolean(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID,
                    NETSNMP_DS_APP_DONT_FIX_PDUS)) {
                pdu = snmp_fix_pdu(response, SNMP_MSG_GET);
                snmp_free_pdu(response);
                response = NULL;
                if (pdu != NULL) {
                    goto retry;
        }
            }
        }                       /* endif -- SNMP_ERR_NOERROR */

    } else if (status == STAT_TIMEOUT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Timeout: No Response from %s.\n",
                session.peername);
        exitval = 1;

    } else {                    /* status == STAT_ERROR */
        snmp_sess_perror("snmpget", ss);
        exitval = 1;

    }                           /* endif -- STAT_SUCCESS */


    if (response)
        snmp_free_pdu(response);
    snmp_close(ss);
    SOCK_CLEANUP;
    return exitval;

}                               /* end main() */
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. It would be helpful to post your code than snmpget code. Check out [this link](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module) and [this link](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Coding_Tutorials)

Comment: @kbr the default is all I have, I am starting from scratch. I am spending most of my time just trying to include headers for this. If there is an easier way to do this without using the snmpget code, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Have you even taken a look at the definition of basic types such as `snmp_session`?